# Is there a way to resolve a conflict between SwipeListener and touch input on the same view?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am making an app with Xamarin.forms targeting iOS, Android, and UWP. I cant get both touch and swipe listeners to work at the same time.

I have a view with a bunch of buttons as children in it. I need to be able to swipe this view left and right and also touch the buttons.

---

**I have tried multiple ways:**

**Attempt #1)** Set a SwipeListener on the background parent view. Doesn't work if the user first touches one of the children buttons. Because the children have a higher z position, they intercept the touch event.

**Attempt #2)** Set a SwipeListener on a view positioned top of everything. Swipe works but then I cant tap any of the buttons. Setting this view's InputTransparent="False" will let me tap the buttons, but then Swipe stops working.

**Attempt #3)** This almost worked. Setup was much like attempt #1, a SwipeListener on background parent view. The difference was each of the buttons had no Click event. Instead I used a TapGestureRecognizer on each of the buttons. This worked great on UWP and iOS. No conflict. But on Android swipe doesn't work as expected if you touch a button at the start of your swipe. It inconsistently works, does nothing, or swipes in the wrong direction.

---

Ill post just a bit of my code. I can post more if wanted. But I'm hoping there may be a high level solution that someone knows about that solves this problem. Thanks in advance for looking.

```
//How I set my buttons' touch recognizer
var touchRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer { NumberOfTapsRequired = 1 };
touchRecognizer.Command = myViewModel.DayButtClickedCommand;
touchBox.GestureRecognizers.Add(touchRecognizer);

//How I set the swipe recognizer
SwipeListener swipeListener = new SwipeListener(MainHompageStackLayout);
swipeListener.SwipedLeft += swipedLeft;
swipeListener.SwipedRight += swipedRight;
```

Comment: Will it meet your requirement if you change your `background parent view` to a `scrollview`?

Comment: Ill give it a shot. Early on in development I abandoned scrollview because of performance issues. Scrollview doesn't do too well when creating a bunch of children inside at runtime. But at this point it may be easier to work with performance issues than my current roadblock. Thanks @Jack Hua - MSFT. I will update once attempted.

Comment: Tweaking the app to use scrollview was becoming a bit too hacky and wasn't turning out to be a viable option in my case. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution that works. Just in case its useful to anyone...

Attempt #3 was not far off. Here is my current setup:

- No buttons and no Click events. TapGestureRecognizer set on all children instead.
- Swipe gesture recognizer on background **parent AND all the children inside.**
- Also I stopped using a 'SwipeListener' class  (a custom swipe listener I found that gives a bit more control over swipe) and switched to the default SwipeGestureRecognizer.

I tested on an iOS simulator, installed on Google Pixel XL, and UWP on a Surface Book. Swipe and touch all work flawlessly now.

**To sum it up, I believe my problem was 2 things:**

1. The **custom SwipeListener** was conflicting with the TapGestureRecognizer in some way.
2. I needed to put **swipe recognition on both the parent** (hidden underneath) **and the children** (layered  above) for consistent swiping.